# Vision BarcodeDetector doesnt read Data Matrix barcodes

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-vision

It reads QR codes just fine. but cant read datamatrix at all! i saw [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/194) that it did work for someone else when the barcode was in the center of the frame, but it doesnt work for me too.

I built it so it should read DATA_MATRIX :

```
detector =
            new BarcodeDetector.Builder(ctx)
                    .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.DATA_MATRIX | Barcode.QR_CODE)
                    .build();
```

Any1 dealt with this issue?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

There could be some reasons:

1) Did you try:

```
detector =
        new BarcodeDetector.Builder(ctx)
                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.DATA_MATRIX)
                .build();
```

so you do not detect QR codes. Because some smartphones are too slow to detect multiple barcodes.

2) Are your google play services up to date?

3) Did you try to go closer to the barcode or go further away?